# ¿Cómo puede optimizar mi código con tidyverse o otras librerías?

Tags: r, lista, bucle-for, datetime, rendimiento

Tengo una lista con 106 tibbles en data_sensor. Cada tibble tiene dos columnas, temperatura y fecha. El vector data_admin tiene 106 valores con fechas. El código funciona correctamente pero el bucle for tratando todos los valores funciona muy lento y no me parece una solución elegante.
La media de rows en cada tibble és de unas 10k.

```
idxend=vector()
for (i in seq_along(data_sensor)){
  for (j in seq_along(data_sensor[[i]][[1]])){
    if (as.Date(data_sensor[[i]][[1]][[j]]) == as.Date(date_admin[i])){
      idxend[i] = j
    } else{
      idxend[i]=idxend[i]
    }
  }
}

> idxend
  [1]  8862    NA 10594  5538  2372  9151  6998  4258 10732  7133  4554  7276  7127  9996  7276
 [16] 10161 12324  4625  6125  5559  5970  4683  6134  4253  8422  7118  6556  6391  9006  3543
 [31]  3031  4219 12177  5117  2942  7124  7287    85  5964  7052  7581 13037  6107  5462  6702
 [46] 10142  4894  6273  4110  8997  6973  6965  4547  6998  6133  7710  5553 10007 11302  9291
 [61]  6991  7859  5260  7136  6035  8569  5025  8639  9296  6127  7132  2095  5256  3902  9991
 [76]  7408  8294  7420  4056  8428  6982  6834  4542  6050 11013  5696 11872  7976  9134  8996
 [91]  6273 12299  9211    NA  7114  6257  9129  6463  7999  6420  7134  9576 10055  9134 12165
[106]    NA
```

He intentado implementar el mismo código con la librería purrr y distintas funciones de tidyverse sin éxito. ¿Cómo podría reducir el tiempo de computo?

Para intentar explicar mejor el caso, adjunto los valores de mi vector y los valores que coinciden en mis lista de tibbles.

```
> date_admin
  [1] "2018-10-07 UTC" "2018-12-29 UTC" "2018-12-13 UTC" "2019-08-09 UTC" "2019-10-10 UTC"
  [6] "2019-04-26 UTC" "2018-11-21 UTC" "2018-08-23 UTC" "2019-07-08 UTC" "2019-11-19 UTC"
 [11] "2019-11-07 UTC" "2018-09-05 UTC" "2018-09-03 UTC" "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC"
 [16] "2018-09-25 UTC" "2019-03-29 UTC" "2018-08-20 UTC" "2018-09-17 UTC" "2019-03-30 UTC"
 [21] "2018-11-07 UTC" "2019-01-01 UTC" "2018-08-31 UTC" "2019-03-27 UTC" "2019-11-10 UTC"
 [26] "2019-04-04 UTC" "2019-10-18 UTC" "2018-09-06 UTC" "2018-09-23 UTC" "2018-09-22 UTC"
 [31] "2019-07-22 UTC" "2018-09-04 UTC" "2019-05-17 UTC" "2018-11-05 UTC" "2018-12-09 UTC"
 [36] "2018-09-03 UTC" "2019-05-21 UTC" "2019-02-22 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2019-06-04 UTC"
 [41] "2018-09-13 UTC" "2018-10-14 UTC" "2019-11-08 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2019-04-12 UTC"
 [46] "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-08-22 UTC" "2018-08-30 UTC" "2018-09-07 UTC" "2018-11-11 UTC"
 [51] "2018-11-01 UTC" "2018-10-01 UTC" "2018-10-22 UTC" "2018-12-03 UTC" "2019-06-06 UTC"
 [56] "2018-09-09 UTC" "2018-09-10 UTC" "2018-09-24 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2018-11-30 UTC"
 [61] "2018-09-20 UTC" "2019-11-20 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2018-10-09 UTC" "2018-09-27 UTC"
 [66] "2019-11-11 UTC" "2018-10-04 UTC" "2018-09-14 UTC" "2019-04-27 UTC" "2018-09-04 UTC"
 [71] "2018-09-11 UTC" "2018-08-14 UTC" "2018-09-01 UTC" "2018-10-01 UTC" "2018-09-25 UTC"
 [76] "2018-09-28 UTC" "2018-09-29 UTC" "2018-10-11 UTC" "2019-03-26 UTC" "2018-10-26 UTC"
 [81] "2018-11-21 UTC" "2018-12-02 UTC" "2018-09-08 UTC" "2019-01-08 UTC" "2018-11-07 UTC"
 [86] "2019-02-05 UTC" "2019-01-21 UTC" "2018-09-11 UTC" "2018-12-17 UTC" "2019-01-15 UTC"
 [91] "2018-08-28 UTC" "2019-01-08 UTC" "2019-05-14 UTC" "2019-01-21 UTC" "2018-11-12 UTC"
 [96] "2018-10-26 UTC" "2019-12-26 UTC" "2020-01-03 UTC" "2020-01-06 UTC" "2020-02-26 UTC"
[101] "2020-02-14 UTC" "2020-01-27 UTC" "2020-01-21 UTC" "2020-03-16 UTC" "2020-02-26 UTC"
[106] "2019-12-31 UTC"
```

Así idxend[1] tal cómo se ve en el output me indica que para mi primer tibble, la fecha date_admin[1] se encuentra en la row 8862.

```
> data_sensor[[1]][[1]][[8862]]
[1] "2018-10-07 23:50:31 UTC"
```

Del mismo modo, en el tercer tibble, date_admin[3] coincide para el valor 10594:

```
    > data_sensor[[3]][[1]][[10594]]
    [1] "2018-12-13 23:58:06 UTC"
```

Ejemplo de datos en el tercer tibble:

```
data_sensor[[3]][[1]]
   [1] "2018-10-01 10:28:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 10:38:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 10:48:06 UTC"
   [4] "2018-10-01 10:58:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 11:08:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 11:18:06 UTC"
   [7] "2018-10-01 11:28:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 11:38:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 11:48:06 UTC"
  [10] "2018-10-01 11:58:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 12:08:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 12:18:06 UTC"
  [13] "2018-10-01 12:28:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 12:38:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 12:48:06 UTC"
  [16] "2018-10-01 12:58:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 13:08:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 13:18:06 UTC"
  [19] "2018-10-01 13:28:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 13:38:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 13:48:06 UTC"
  [22] "2018-10-01 13:58:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 14:08:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 14:18:06 UTC"
  [25] "2018-10-01 14:28:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 14:38:06 UTC" "2018-10-01 14:48:06 UTC"
```

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar en palabras no en código lo que buscas?

Comment: Tengo una lista de fechas en date_admin que me ínidican el que quiero que sea el final de mis 106 series temporales respectivamente. Con estos for pretendo identificar el índice en el que se encuentran esas fechas en mis lista de 106 tibbles, para posteriormente, eliminar todos los valores a partir de ese índice y dejar limpias mis series temporales. Supongo que con paquetes de dplyr y tidyverse hay algún modo más simple de solucionarlo pero aún no tengo fluidez.

Comment: Bien, estoy entendiendo que tienes 106 fechas en un vector (no sé si son distintas o siempre la misma) y lo que buscas es quedarte solo con las filas menores a dichas fechas en cada uno de los df de la lista. ¿es así?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho las fechas són distintas. He intentado explicar mejor el caso mostrando el vector. Las fechas motradas en data_sensor estan en formato POSIXct, por eso las convierto as.Date(). Las fechas en el data_sensor son lecturas de temperatura cada 10 mins. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según llego a entender, tienes un vector `date_admin` con `n` fechas, cada una individualmente sería el argumento para filtrar filas de un `data.frame` especifico ubicado en la lista `data_sensor`.

Imaginemos un ejemplo de datos más acotado pero similar al tuyo:

```
df <- data.frame(fecha = seq(ISOdate(2011,8,1), by = "month", length.out = 10),
                 tempertura = runif(10))

data_sensor <- list()
data_sensor[[1]] <- df
data_sensor[[2]] <- df

data_sensor

[[1]]
                 fecha tempertura
1  2011-08-01 12:00:00  0.6306733
2  2011-09-01 12:00:00  0.8181778
3  2011-10-01 12:00:00  0.1969709
4  2011-11-01 12:00:00  0.9363699
5  2011-12-01 12:00:00  0.1491351
6  2012-01-01 12:00:00  0.4043176
7  2012-02-01 12:00:00  0.1546033
8  2012-03-01 12:00:00  0.5951968
9  2012-04-01 12:00:00  0.1720075
10 2012-05-01 12:00:00  0.7086279

[[2]]
                 fecha tempertura
1  2011-08-01 12:00:00  0.6306733
2  2011-09-01 12:00:00  0.8181778
3  2011-10-01 12:00:00  0.1969709
4  2011-11-01 12:00:00  0.9363699
5  2011-12-01 12:00:00  0.1491351
6  2012-01-01 12:00:00  0.4043176
7  2012-02-01 12:00:00  0.1546033
8  2012-03-01 12:00:00  0.5951968
9  2012-04-01 12:00:00  0.1720075
10 2012-05-01 12:00:00  0.7086279
```

Tenemos una lista con dos elementos, cada uno un `data.frame`. Ahora bien, imaginemos un vector, por como es este ejemplo, con dos fechas, que cada una se correspondería con la fecha a filtrar.

```
set.seed(2021)
date_admin <- sample(df$fecha,2)
date_admin
[1] "2012-02-01 12:00:00 GMT" "2012-01-01 12:00:00 GMT"
```

Para lo que vamos a hacer, nos va a convenir transformar el vector en un `data.frame`:

```
date_admin <- data.frame(index=1:2, fecha=sample(df$fecha,2))
date_admin

  index               fecha
1     1 2012-05-01 12:00:00
2     2 2012-02-01 12:00:00
```

Con la lista también nos va a convenir convertirla en un único `data.frame` con una columna `Index` que referencie al índice del elemento de la lista original.

```
data_sensor %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "index")
```

Ahora teniendo dos `data.frames` podemos unirlos horizontalmente mediante un `left_join` por el `Index`, y de esta forma podremos filtrar fácilmente las fechas:

```
data_sensor %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "index") %>% 
  mutate(index = as.numeric(index)) %>% 
  left_join(date_admin, by="index") %>% 
  filter(fecha.x < fecha.y) %>% 
  select(index, fecha = fecha.x, tempertura)

   index               fecha tempertura
1      1 2011-08-01 12:00:00  0.6306733
2      1 2011-09-01 12:00:00  0.8181778
3      1 2011-10-01 12:00:00  0.1969709
4      1 2011-11-01 12:00:00  0.9363699
5      1 2011-12-01 12:00:00  0.1491351
6      1 2012-01-01 12:00:00  0.4043176
7      1 2012-02-01 12:00:00  0.1546033
8      1 2012-03-01 12:00:00  0.5951968
9      1 2012-04-01 12:00:00  0.1720075
10     2 2011-08-01 12:00:00  0.6306733
11     2 2011-09-01 12:00:00  0.8181778
12     2 2011-10-01 12:00:00  0.1969709
13     2 2011-11-01 12:00:00  0.9363699
14     2 2011-12-01 12:00:00  0.1491351
15     2 2012-01-01 12:00:00  0.4043176
```

Si eventualmente sigues necesitando que los datos se manejen en una lista, puedes transformar los datos, agregando al final del pipe:

```
group_split(index)
```

Por otro lado, si sigues necesitando el índice de la fila dónde coincide cada fecha, puedes hacer algo muy similar a lo anterior:

```
  data_sensor %>%
    bind_rows(.id = "index") %>% 
    mutate(index = as.numeric(index)) %>% 
    left_join(date_admin, by="index") %>% 
    mutate(id = ifelse(fecha.x == fecha.y, row_number(), NA)) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(id)) %>% 
    select(index, id)

  index id
1     1 10
2     2 17
```

Comment: Funciona! El único problema es que en lugar de 106 indices aparacen 13788 dado que cada dia tiene varios sensados (no me explique respecto este detalle). Creo que podré encontrarle solucion a eso. Y efectivamente mejora el rendimiento. Muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho!